# How to concat() an array with the second array showing in front of the first?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to concat two arrays, but have the second array show up first.

Example:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

const combinedArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(combinedArr);
```

I know you could simply switch arr1 with arr2 and reverse the order `arr2.concat(arr1)`, but is there a better way or different way of doing this?

Comment: How could it be better than `arr2.concat(arr1)`?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use ES6, use the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
[ ...arr2, ...arr1 ]
```

Comment: Great answer not only does this work , but it is with the updated es6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could try the unshift property: `arr1.unshift(arr2);`

Comment: That won't do what you want

Comment: You'll need to either use spread syntax `arr1.unshift(...arr2)` or play with `apply` `arr1.unshift.apply(arr1, arr2)`